# Expanding div height in CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

So on my page, I have a two column layout - 75% (left - blue) and 25% (right - red). I can't get the red column to fill. In Chrome's inspector I see that the `container` classed `<div>` has expanded vertically to the size of `#left`,  but I just cannot coax `#right` to expand appropriately. Here's the jfiddle link for my css and html (followed by the code itself in case you don't want to click to tinker):

Just one quick note: In my actual development code I don't use blue and red (left and right div background colours) - I use white and navy, respectively.

http://jsfiddle.net/EG3zb/

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="left">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam id nunc bibendum ligula tempus interdum a ac urna. Fusce sed nunc molestie, consequat orci eu, vehicula orci. Suspendisse nec leo sit amet tellus varius feugiat. Maecenas lacinia neque euismod, tincidunt nisi et, fermentum ipsum. Vivamus ut gravida velit, vitae ultrices ante. Nullam varius mattis tellus, vitae consectetur tortor porttitor eu. Donec congue eros mauris. Ut consequat aliquam mattis. Aliquam non neque eros.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        Blah.
    </div>
</div>
```

And the accompanying CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#left, #right {
    padding-top: 2%;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: blue;;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is working

```
.container {
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
display:flex;
}
.container #left,.container #right{
    -webkit-flex: auto;
    -ms-flex:auto;
    flex:auto;
}
```

here is working demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/mauryaashish945/EG3zb/5/

Comment: To be honest I like this answer more as it uses flex. But does this raise compatibility issues?

Comment: It also seems to throw padding out the window.

Comment: to be honest,i think flex is not supported in safari. but you can use bob-flex which is supported in all major browser

Answer (score 1):

Instead of default `display:block` you can use `display:table-cell` so there is no need for `float:left\right` :

```
#left, #right {
   display:table-cell;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/EG3zb/3/)

Comment: I ddnt  understand  the behavior of change..can you explain more

Comment: I swear I've tried this before and it didn't work, but I just tried it again and it did. I feel so tired and defeated by CSS. Thanks!

Comment: @Pilot : to make divs the same height OP can use `table-cell` layout instead of `block`.

Comment: @Pilot : with `float:left/right` they are displayed as `block` elements within the normal flow so `height` is different .

Comment: @Notulysses no..The root cause is with `flot:left/right` they are rendered with height equal to content height not the parent height..Thanks for addressing comment..Asked for cause just for adding value to your answer and you should not fix the bug unless until you know what the bug is

Comment: @Pilot: As I said above they are positioned within the normal flow, so it is quite obvious that their height is calculated upon it's content,not parent's.

Comment: Is there a way to force #right to be at 100% the size of the viewport? I tried `min-height: 100vh` for #right but it's not working for me.

Comment: Kind of - I'd like to achieve an effect where by default, the right side has the height of at-least the viewport. In essence the same effect as min-height: 100vh except without having to stretch too far (by using, for example, 100em) and cause unnecessary scrolling.

Comment: @Mephoros : `vh` and `vw` have a very poor support, so I think it is not an option. I guess you are looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EG3zb/10/)